# tee: invalid option -- 's'

Tags: java, jitsi

I have to use the command

```
echo DISPLAY=":99" | sudo tee -a /etc/environment Xvfb $DISPLAY -screen 0 1280x720x60 -ac -dpi 96 +extension RANDR 2>&1 > /dev/null &
```

to make the Jitsi-meet-torture tool working on my machine. I found it on their community discussions and it got my tool working eventhough I have no idea of its function. But sometimes when I run the command, It gives me the following error.

```
tee: invalid option -- 's' 
Try 'tee --help' for more information.
```

I have no idea what cause this error. Can someone please help me to resolve this?

Comment: i suspect the `-screen` is being passed to `tee` instead of `xvfb`.

Comment: can you please suggest me how to correct the command?